# Hashmap size declaration

Tags: java, collections

I have initialized one hashmap as

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
hm.put(1,"John");
hm.put(2, "Bob");
hm.put(3, "Alice");
```

and also initialized another one as

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm2 = new HashMap<Integer,String>(1);  
hm.put(1,"John");
hm.put(2, "Bob");
hm.put(3, "Alice");
```

But could not find any difference, in what way both of them differs in ? is there any difference or both are the same ?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: the default capacity of a hashmap is 16 and combined with the loadfactor it alters the size when it reaches the threshold. So its always good to chose the optimum value of capacity based on how many elements you would put into the hashmap later and also the load factor

Comment: Iteration over keys and entries in the first will be slightly slower, but otherwise, they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI:

> The Java Collections API's provide Java developers with a set of
>   classes and interfaces that makes it easier to handle collections of
>   objects. In a sense Collection's works a bit like arrays, except their
>   size can change dynamically, and they have more advanced behaviour
>   than arrays.

Check [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) documentation for details. Below is the documentation for `HashMap` constructors that you have used :

1. HashMap()

> Constructs an empty HashMap with the default initial capacity (16) and
>   the default load factor (0.75).

2. HashMap(int initialCapacity)

> Constructs an empty HashMap with the specified initial capacity and
>   the default load factor (0.75).

Answer (score 0):

The version of HashMap constructor with an initial size argument is there for performance reasons - the semantics of the map are unaffected.   If you had a large number of values to add, you could set the initial value and prevent some re-hashing as you added them all.   A value of '1' turns out not to do anything at all different than no value constructor, though (only "kicks in" after a larger initial value...)

Answer (score 0):

The firs one `constructs an empty HashMap with the default initial capacity (16) and the default load factor (0.75).`

The other one `Constructs an empty HashMap with the specified initial capacity and the default load factor (0.75)`
 (viz in your case `1`).

You can look in to `javadoc` for more.